# Alignment issue in ireport pdf RedHat server for jdk 1.5

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, redhat

Jasper report pdf is in correct alignment in jdk 1.5 but in jdk 1.6 it is wrong in Redhat.Why red hat behaves like that for jasper report where in ubuntu there is no issue.Is there any other settings required to fix it.The Redhat is 5.4 version and ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this type of problem is always font extensions. The alignment is different because the other server has different fonts available. Use font extensions to ensure that you have exactly the fonts you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mdahlman for your reply...I used proper font extension which worked both redhat jdk 1.5 and ubuntu for both jdk 1.5 and 1.6 .The font i used Trebuchet MS so it is also added in jar list.it Worked fine.My problem was with jdk 1.5 and 1.6 in redhat but i found the

java version "1.6.0"
OpenJDK  Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0-b09)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 1.6.0-b09, mixed mode)

The font is not working with correct alignment in RedHat

But in below jdk 1.6 version it is working fine

java version "1.6.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.1-b02, mixed mode)

However i fixed my bug with jre build 1.6.0_15-b03.